# Place the business logic in Java Beans?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I was [reading this page](http://www.jcorporate.com/expresso/doc/edg/edg_WhatIsMVC.html) and I found the following statement:

> MVC in Java Server Pages
>
> Now that we have a convenient
>   architucture to separate the view, how
>   can we leverage that? Java Server
>   Pages (JSP) becomes more interesting
>   because the HTML content can be
>   separated from the Java business
>   objects. JSP can also make use of Java
>   Beans. **The business logic could be placed inside Java Beans.** If the
>   design is architected correctly, a Web
>   Designer could work with HTML on the
>   JSP site without interfering with the
>   Java developer.

Interestingly in my textbook I pulled the following quote:

> In the MVC architecture... the
>   original request is always handled by
>   a servlet. **The servlet invokes the business logic and data access code and creates beans to represent the results (that’s the model).** Then, the
>   servlet decides which Java Server Page
>   is appropriate to present those
>   particular results and forwards the
>   request there (the JSP is the view).
>   The servlet decides what business
>   logic code applies and which JSP
>   should present the results (the
>   servlet is the controller).

The two statements seem slightly contradicting. What is the best way to use beans: should we place business logic in them or should we only place results in them? Are there ways in which beans are inadequate for representing a model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's also pretty common for business logic to be placed in classes with a suffix of Manager.  Although some people put business logic on the data object bean itself I find it best when methods on the data object only do simple functions that do not rely on any external dependencies.  All the rest of the business logic I place in a Manager bean that is capable of using multiple data object javabeans and other external dependencies to follow the business logic.  So for example an AccountBean would contain the account fields and maybe a few simple methods that use those fields to compute and return a value, or format a field.  All the business logic would be in a Manager, possibly an AccountManagerBean.

Comment: Does your JSP use the Manager bean or does it only use the model bean?

Comment: Your view hopefully has something behind the JSP, in Struts it's and Action class, in some places it's a servlet class, other frameworks use other things.  In that Java class you can use the Manager to find, update, add, delete passing your data bean.  In the JSP it's best to keep as much Java out of it as possible so I would only use the view data javabean in there and keep the Manager out.

Comment: I find all this contradicting. Because I feel in most texts about JavaBeans they seem to put the emphasis on them being simple datacontainers that should almost exclusively have only getters and setters, which somehow doesnt play along with my view of how a buissinessobject should look. I respect your answer, totally! Just would like some input on your thoughts about JavaBeans having those "restrictions" with getters and setters, then adding additional methods to add logic. Maybe I missunderstood the whole JavaBeans thing? I really dont know. :-o

Answer (score 3):

The second statement is basically telling about two javabeans: one for business logic and other for the model. So, yes the business logic can still be placed in javabeans. The javabean for the business logic can encapsulate the javabean for model as its property.

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // ...
}

public class UserManager {
    private User user;
    // ...

    public void login() {
        // ...
    }

    public void logout() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any situations where the bean may not be suitable for presenting a model? I have not encountered enough situations to have a good example, but what would be an example of a model unsuitable for beans?

Comment: In addition: are business beans used in the JSP just like a model bean is used?

Comment: I don't see situations where a bean may not be suitable to represent a model. And yes, you can use it in JSP the same way; to access the properties. The actions are to be invoked by the controller depending on the request.